# vue cant show the second modal form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a form two buttons when I click on each button it should open its own form and close the main, but it works only for the form that is higher in HTML code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXKaw.png)
I have a form two buttons when I click on each button it should open its own form and close the main, but it works only for the form that is higher in HTML code[enter image description here

Code:

```
<div class="login">
        <div class="login-button"><a @click="open_login_window = !open_login_window"><div class="login-img"></div></a></div>
        <transition name="fade">
         <div class="login-window" v-if="open_login_window">
          <div class="buttons">
           <button class="btn header-btn btn-log" @click="open_sign_window = !open_sign_window, open_login_window = !open_login_window">вход</button>
           <button class="btn header-btn btn-reg" @click="open_reg_window = !open_reg_window, open_login_window = !open_login_window">регистрация</button> 
          </div>
          <div class="icons">
           <div class="icon"><div class="icon_1"><a href=""></a></div></div>
           <div class="icon"><div class="icon_2"><a href=""></a></div></div>
           <div class="icon"><div class="icon_3"><a href=""></a></div></div>
           <div class="icon"><div class="icon_4"><a href=""></a></div></div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <transition name="fade">
          <div class="sign-window"  v-click-outside="close_sign_window" v-if="open_sign_window">
           <form action="">
            <h3>вход</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email..."><input type="text" placeholder="пароль...">
            <a>забыли пароль?</a>
            <div class="icons">
             <div class="icon"><div class="icon_1"><a href=""></a></div></div>
             <div class="icon"><div class="icon_2"><a href=""></a></div></div>
             <div class="icon"><div class="icon_3"><a href=""></a></div></div>
             <div class="icon"><div class="icon_4"><a href=""></a></div></div>
            </div> 
            <button class="btn header-btn btn-log">войти</button>
           </form>
          </div>
         </transition>
         <transition name="fade">
          <div class="reg-window" v-click-outside="close_reg_window" v-if="open_reg_window">
           <form action="">
             <h3>регистрация</h3>
             <input type="text" placeholder="email..."><input type="text" placeholder="пароль...">
             <div class="check-block">
              <h4>Ваша роль на сайте</h4>
              <div class="input-box">
               <label class="checkbox">Пользователь
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="mark"></span>
               </label>
               <label class="checkbox">Участник
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="mark"></span>
               </label>
               <label class="checkbox">Компания
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="mark"></span>
               </label>
               <div class="select-block">
                <label class="checkbox">
                 <span class="mark"></span>
                 <input type="checkbox">
                 Принять <ins>пользовательское соглашение</ins>
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox">
                 <span class="mark"></span>
                 <input type="checkbox">
                 Принять <br> <ins>политику конфиденциальности</ins>
                </label>
               </div>
              </div>
             <button class="btn header-btn btn-reg">регистрация</button> 
             </div>
           </form>
          </div>
         </transition>
        </transition>
       </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
import ClickOutside from 'vue-click-outside'
export default {
  name: 'Header',
  data () {

    return {
     open_education_list: false,
     open_work_list: false,
     open_housing_list: false,
     open_rest_list: false,
     open_login_window: false,
     open_mob_menu: false,
     open_login_window: false,
     open_reg_window: false,
     open_sign_window: false,
    }
  },
   methods: {
    close_reg_window(){
     this.open_reg_window = false,
     this.open_login_window = true
    },
    open_mob_menu(){
     this.open_education_list = false,
     this.open_work_list = false,
     this.open_housing_list = false,
     this.open_rest_list = false
    },
    close_sign_window(){
     this.open_sign_window = false,
     this.open_login_window = true
    }
  },
  directives: {
    ClickOutside
  }
}
</script>
```

if i delete one of form, other will be show